# what's the limit of cardinals can be proved to exist in ZFC

Tags: large-cardinals

what is the smallest cardinal k can not be proved to exist in ZFC?And what is the smallest cardinal k ,that the existence of k can imply CON(ZFC)?

Comment: Please be more precise. Smallest in what sense?

Comment: smallest means k can not be proved to exist in ZFC,but k has cardinality smaller than any other cardinal can not be proved to exist in ZFC.

Comment: That's not precise. How are you measuring size? There are countable models of set theory that are not $\omega$ models. We cannot prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that any of its non-standard natural numbers exist, but there is no least one. Is that the answer?

Comment: $\aleph_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the proof-theoretic ordinal of ZFC.

Comment: Define that $\kappa$ is a *huhao* cardinal, if Con(ZFC) holds and $\kappa$ is zero. If ZFC is consistent, then ZFC does not prove the existence of a huhao cardinal; the existence of a huhao cardinal implies Con(ZFC); and a huhao cardinal, when it exists, is the smallest of any cardinal.

Answer (score 8):

This was going to be a comment but it got too long.  I think what needs more precision is not only "smallest" but the notion of a cardinal being proved to exist in ZFC. A cardinal can't actually occur in a theorem of ZFC; what can occur is a definition of a (species of) cardinal.  But such definitions can be pretty weird unless you impose some constraints on them.  Consider for example the following (definable) properties that a cardinal $\kappa$ might have:

(A) $\kappa$ is weakly compact, and if there exists a supercompact cardinal then $\kappa$ is measurable.

(B) $\kappa$ is inaccessible, and if there exists a supercompact cardinal then $\kappa$ is supercompact.

ZFC cannot prove the existence of cardinals of either of these sorts.  But which is smaller?  If there is a supercompact cardinal, then the first $\kappa$ satisfying (A) is smaller than the first satsifying (B).  But if there is no supercompact cardinal, then the ordering is reversed.

[A joke that I heard attributed to Tony Martin: Theorem. The ordinals are not well-ordered. Proof: For every large-cardinal definition there is a smaller one.]